# What is a Russian Word™?

Tags: pattern, language, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Russian Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| RUSSIAN Words™ | Not RUSSIAN Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| MOTHER | SISTER |
| GENETICS | CELL |
| ERRAND | CREDIT |
| INACCURATE | UNTRUE |
| HELICOPTER | ROTORCRAFT |
| POLICE | ARMY |
| CAGE | BIRD |
| NANOSECOND | MILISECOND |
| HEALER | DOCTOR |
| PRINCE | PURPLE |
| CUBISM | PAINTING |
| SEASHORE | SUNSET |
| BANANA | STRAWBERRY |

Or, in a CSV:

```
RUSSIAN Words™,Not RUSSIAN Words™
MOTHER, SISTER
GENETICS, CELL
ERRAND, CREDIT
INACCURATE, UNTRUE
HELICOPTER, ROTORCRAFT
POLICE, ARMY
CAGE, BIRD
NANOSECOND, MILISECOND
HEALER, DOCTOR
PRINCE, PURPLE
CUBISM, PAINTING
SEASHORE, SUNSET
BANANA, STRAWBERRY
```

These are not the only examples of Russian Words™, many more exist.

**What makes a word Russian?**

Comment: Дa. It means 'Yes." I apologize for this terrible joke. Not worth a proper answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Russian Word™

> Can be decomposed into pairs of letters, each which is a chemical element symbol. For instance, MOTHER = Mo Th Er, or Molybdenum, Thorium, Erbium. SISTER fails because St is not a chemical element symbol.

The relevance of "Russian":

> The person who created the modern periodic table, Mendeleev, was a Russian.

Comment: I like this, and +1! By your rule it is amusing to note that inaccurate spelled correctly is _not_ a Russian word!

Comment: Good job ! And good catch, @El-Guest. In fact, spelled correctly (edited the question), it is still a Russian word ;), just made a mistake typing it in this question