# What is an Earth Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

The Earth is composed with many various elements or objects.
But some of them belong to the Earth Word™, some of them don't.

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Earth Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{1.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Earth }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  BANANA          }&\text{        APPLE           }\\ \hline
\text{  SOUTH           }&\text{        NORTH           }\\ \hline
\text{  AMERICA         }&\text{        CANADA          }\\ \hline
\text{  SOCCER          }&\text{        FOOTBALL        }\\ \hline
\text{  SPIN            }&\text{        ROTATE          }\\ \hline
\text{  HOMOGENEOUS     }&\text{        HETEROGENEOUS   }\\ \hline
\text{  COSTCO          }&\text{        WALMART         }\\ \hline
\text{  WINDOWS         }&\text{        LINUX           }\\ \hline
\text{  FEBRUARY        }&\text{        JANUARY         }\\ \hline
\text{  ACCEPT          }&\text{        DECLINE         }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: See also: [What is a Scientific Word™](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/20109)

Comment: See also: [What is a Russian Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/81762)

Comment: Seems Chemistry is popular :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An Earth word is a word which:

> can be made entirely from symbols of elements in the Periodic Table.

As follows:

> BANANA = Ba + Na + Na
>  SOUTH = S + O + U + Th
>  AMERICA = Am + Er + I + Ca
>  SOCCER = S + O + C + C + Er
>  SPIN = S + P + In (or S + P + I + N)
>  HOMOGENEOUS = Ho + Mo + Ge + Ne + O + U + S
>  COSTCO = C + O + S + Tc + O
>  WINDOWS = W + I + Nd + O + W + S
>  FEBRUARY = Fe + Br + U (or B + Ru) + Ar + Y
>  ACCEPT = Ac + Ce + Pt

The non-Earth words fail because of the following reasons:

> APPLE - there is no 'Pl', 'L' or 'Le' element to get the L;
>  NORTH - there is no 'Or', 'R' or 'Rt' element to get the R;
>  CANADA - there is no 'Ad' or 'Da' element to get the D;
>  FOOTBALL - there is no 'L' element to get the final L;
>  ROTATE - there is no 'R' or 'Ro' element to get the R;
>  HETEROGENEOUS - if beginning He + Te, there is no 'Ro' element; if attempting to use 'Er' instead, there is no 'Et' or 'T' element to get the T;
>  WALMART - there is no 'Rt' or 'T' element to get the T;
>  LINUX - there is no 'Ux' or 'X' element to get the X;
>  JANUARY - no elements begin with a 'J';
>  DECLINE - there is no 'D' or 'De' element to get the 'D'.

There is a nod to the solution in the question since:

> *The Earth is composed with many various **elements***

Plus, regarding the name:

> 'Earth' is one of the four classic **elements** (along with air, water and fire).

Comment: This can be helpful: http://www.elementfinder.info/

Comment: @JanIvan Well that's one to bookmark! Thanks :)

Comment: @Stiv Great Job! You have fully interpreted the question within short time. The example took me a lot of time and paperwork(This is my first home-grown question on the site) :P

Comment: Well, nice job @Conifers - oddly enough my first question here also involved words constructed from elements! (Great minds...) +1